# How to retrieve Facebook friends count with PHP SDK v5?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve my Facebook's friends count with the [PHP SDK v5](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk).

```
// $access_token is already being successfully filled, using this example:
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

$response = $fb->get('/me/friends', $access_token);

# obtain user object
$user = $response->getGraphEdge();

# test
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the result:

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object
(
    [request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object
        (
            [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 1864094063814172
                    [secret:protected] => d71134d1a3efd829060395e73288cc4b
                )

            [accessToken:protected] => EAAafYjiAZAhwBALvYZARvbP4ZCUucDp1yqcK4yIZBVZC3rxnhivyaKwJzAQzXGmb2E6ZBEKAZClKtw07dzDWLbZCKxk1XlgMzKl4NGvfHkyTPFsdv9wD2y7YpyuFPZAhZCQqry1ZCx5pCKXbqZBg0S1nckijNG57McCoQGwZD
            [method:protected] => GET
            [endpoint:protected] => /me/friends
            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                )

            [params:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [files:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [eTag:protected] => 
            [graphVersion:protected] => v2.8
        )

    [metaData:protected] => Array
        (
            [summary] => Array
                (
                    [total_count] => 560
                )

        )

    [parentEdgeEndpoint:protected] => 
    [subclassName:protected] => 
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

How do I get the **total_count** value (560)? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, your `Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge` [has a `getMetaData` function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0) to access that `metaData:protected` section.

Comment: Why do they do it like this? IDK, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: do you happen to know if there is a similar method for `$fb->get('/me?fields=cover')` ? The "cover" data also comes in a protected array, but I can't find anything like the `getMetaData` method for [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

Comment: Use the getField function